# Exploitation of data provider elements inside test as array, using testNG

Tags: java, arrays, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I created a selenium testNG webdriver automation programe which grab data fome excel sheet and use them for fill some fields and execute some tasks,

So I wrote a code that is successfully executed when the tasks are hard coded,but I want to avoid hard coding and lot of repetition inside `@test`, so I injected an array list in which I want to exploite @DataProvider elements,

this is the code

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.excelreader.utility.getDataUtil;

public class testTab2 {
    static WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Browsers drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/title-setup/paperback/new/details?ref_=kdp_BS_D_cr_ti");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ap_email']")).sendKeys("email");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'ap_password\']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signInSubmit\"]")).click();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void newTab() 
    {
        driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        driver.get("https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/title-setup/paperback/new/details?ref_=kdp_BS_D_cr_ti");

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getTestData")
    protected static void testAmazon1(String innerPath, String coverPath, String book_Title, String subtitle,
              String f_Name, String l_Name, String Description, String keyword1, String keyword2, 
              String keyword3, String keyword4, String keyword5, String keyword6, String keyword7, 
              String category_1, String category_2, String step_1, String step_2, String step_3, 
              String step_4, String step_5, String step_6, String step_7, String step_a, String step_b, 
              String step_c, String step_d, String step_e, String step_f, String step_g, String step_1final,String step_2final) throws Exception 
    {
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Thread.sleep(4000);


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='data-print-book-categories-button-proto-announce']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);



        String[] category_A = new String [7];

        category_A [0] = step_1;
        category_A [1] = step_2;
        category_A [2] = step_3;
        category_A [3] = step_4;
        category_A [4] = step_5;
        category_A [5] = step_6;
        category_A [6] = step_7;

        int i = 0;
        int index=0;
        while (i<=6) {
            if (category_A [i] != "kk") {
                i++;
            } else {
                index=i;
                System.out.println(index);
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j=0; j<=index-2 ; j++) {

            String expand = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='icon-" + category_A [j] + "']")).getAttribute("class");
            System.out.println("expand befor execution is: "+ expand);

            String icon_plus = "icon expand-icon";
            if(expand.equals(icon_plus)) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='icon-" + category_A [j] + "']")).click();}
                     else {
                        System.out.println(category_A [j] + " is expanded");
                    }
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'"+ step_1final +"')]")).click();
        System.out.println("the following checkbox :" + step_1final + "is checked");

    }



      @DataProvider(parallel = false)
      public Iterator<Object[]> getTestData() {
          ArrayList<Object[]> testData = getDataUtil.getDataFromExcel();
          return testData.iterator();

      }

}
```

But the program continues to run until it reaches the array and it gives me this message:

Output

```
Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-refs/branch-heads/XXXX@{#XXX}) on port XXXXX
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
janv. 27, 2020 5:30:51 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

If any one has a solution, I need to solve this problem.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replace that **if statement**

```
 if (category_A [i] != "kk") {
```

whith this

```
 String breaker = "kk"
 if ( !category_A [i].contentEquals(breaker)) {
```

and it works, I still dont know why but its working, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included details of what error message you saw, but looking at your code, am guessing that you perhaps received an error message that looks like below:

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
[public void com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn59935793.DataProviderSample.testMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
Data provider mismatch
Method: testMethod([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(java.util.Collections$SingletonList) [a]]
```

There's a problem with your test code.

Your test method has the below signature:

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "getTestData")
    protected static void testAmazon1(String innerPath, String coverPath, String book_Title, String subtitle,
              String f_Name, String l_Name, String Description, String keyword1, String keyword2, 
              String keyword3, String keyword4, String keyword5, String keyword6, String keyword7, 
              String category_1, String category_2, String step_1, String step_2, String step_3, 
              String step_4, String step_5, String step_6, String step_7, String step_a, String step_b, 
              String step_c, String step_d, String step_e, String step_f, String step_g, String step_1final,String step_2final) throws Exception 
    {
```

But your data provider is returning back an `Iterator<Object[]>`.

Based on the below line of code in your data provider

`ArrayList<Object[]> testData = getDataUtil.getDataFromExcel();`

Its not possible to figure out what is the exact return type of your `getDataFromExcel()` method.

But going by what you explained in your test method, I guess your `getDataFromExcel()` is perhaps returning back a list, and you are trying to map it to individual elements in your test method.

That wont work.

Below is a sample that shows how to work with `List` directly.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProviderSample {
  @DataProvider(name = "dp")
  public Iterator<Object[]> getData() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new Object[] {Collections.singletonList("a")}, new Object[] {Arrays.asList("x", "y")})
        .iterator();
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void testMethod(List<String> data) {
    data.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you mr Krishnan for your effort, please check my answer in which I gave updates.
thank you

Comment: @krishnan - could you please help me in this testng question ? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253369/testng-shorthand-to-create-arrays-inside-data-provider

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - output**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@id,'self--help_self--management_general')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-3', revision: '8c567de6dc'
System info: host: 'UNKNOUN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.102', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '13.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Users\moad\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52780}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 22669af4ff7fb4956b5951fd1aa2f1c6
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[contains(@id,'self--help_self--management_general')]}
```

I added a `System.out.println(category_A [i] + " index = " + i);`  after the **if line**, and what I found is that the array is actually reciving data, but the problem is in **if else condition**. I found that even the *if* condition is not satisfied, it continues executing it untile the last element.

and this is the output I got.

```
nonfiction index = 0
self--help index = 1
self--help_self--management index = 2
kk index = 3
kk index = 4
kk index = 5
kk index = 6
```

I don't know the raison of this?.